# Format with "autopep8" failed. Please install "autopep8" in your python environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

i had installed autopep8 in the path: /usr/bin , but when i use save format in the vscode , its cannot work. mention that :"Format with "autopep8" failed. Please install "autopep8" in your python environment". how can i do? can anyone solved this trouble?

Comment: First you have to activate your virtual enviroment and then u can install your "autopep8"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just install it in your python environment, `pip install autopep8`.

Comment: thanks for warm-heart responses, the status is that i had installed autopep8 in my enviroment, and i can find autopep8 in the path: /usr/bin, but the vscode cannot find  the autopep8 when i want to saving my codes format.

Comment: when i saving codes in vscode, its mentions as : Format with "autopep8" failed,please install autopep8 in your python environment.

Comment: does its meaning that the python can not find "autopep8"?

Comment: when i tape "pip install autopep8"

Comment: the result is:
Requirement already satisfied: autopep8 in /home/ruizhong.wang/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle>=2.8.0 in /home/ruizhong.wang/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from autopep8) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toml in /home/ruizhong.wang/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from autopep8) (0.10.2)